# Ubuntu sqldeveloper network adapter could not establish the connection hr database

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with my sqldeveloper on Ubuntu 14.
 When I try to connect to default database hr (login hr, pass hr, host: localhost, sid: orcl) I get an error: "network adapter could not establish the connection".

What should I do?
Ask me additional questions if necessary.

Comment: Is your listener started? Is the database up and running? Can you connect to it with sqlplus?

Comment: Well, did you start your database? Did you even install one?

Comment: I'm install only sqldeveloper.

Comment: SQL Developer is not a database and doesn't contain one. You'll need to install an Oracle database if you want to use one on your machine.

Comment: You can provide a link to the database? On Windows, I have the same sqldeveloper and everything works.

Comment: Look at the connection settings you're using on Windows. If that is pointing to a database on something other than localhost try the same settings from Ubuntu, to connect to the same database. If you want a new database then that is a whole different, much larger topic, too broad to tackel here.

Comment: IIRC SQL plus will be installed if Oracle is installed. So just search for how to use it and try verifying your DB is reachable from your Ubuntu box. Also, you may want to check if your Ubuntu box can reach same network your Windows box can. If I get you right, Windows machine sees the DB? Then see @AlexPoole's comment.

Comment: Ok. Installs oracle database express edition. I also tried to connect with an external sql server and it does not work (on windows with the same data I join without a problem).

Comment: sql plus not installed together with sqldeveloper

Answer (score 1):

please , first start your listener if in ubantu environment as

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

then start your sql developer.